Excel formula as string in VBA works without "=" but doesn t work with the "="
I have the following line in my vba code:
Cells(c.Row, 3).Value = "=NB.SI($KM$1:KM9;KM9)"

NB.SI being the countif formula in French.
The line above doesn't work.
However if I just change the code by erasing the "=" sign:
Cells(c.Row, 3).Value = "NB.SI($KM$1:KM9;KM9)"

Then I get the right formula but as a string. I just need to add the "=" in front manually in the cell for it to work.
How can I get Excel to simply accept my "=" sign in front of the formula without putting me an Error 1004?

You have to use Cells(c.Row, 3).Formula = "=NB.SI($KM$1:KM9;KM9)" instead of .value

I tried before posting and again now. Doesn t work better with .formula. I get the exact same issue

You need to use Formula and you need to provide the leading =, else Excel will not know that you want to write a formula and put the content as string. However, you need to provide the english name of the functions (I think it's COUNTIF) and use a comma as separator (or use FormulaLocal, which I don't recommend, keep your code language indepenedent)

It works indeed while typing the formula string in english. (regardless if I put .formula or .value as it is stored as a string I guess.
That s annoying but at least it works thanks.

VBA is designed in English so, when entering formulas with VBA you have to use them in English language and syntax. With syntax I mean; , as parameter separators

@Haluk The requirements of the Formula property of the Range object have nothing to do with the VBA design, the VBA language and the fact that VBA itself uses commas as its argument separator. Otherwise it would be quite difficult to explain why the FormulaLocal property accepts formulas in non-English, and how it is possible to manipulate the various methods of the Excel object model from environments other than VBA, that may have argument rules completely different than VBA.

@Greg I am trying to say that; if someone is trying to use Formula property in VBA, she/he must use the function names and arguments in English and use commas as the argument/parameter separators.... and this due how VBA is designed. So, are saying that this is not correct, or am I misunderstanding you?

@Haluk It is correct that someone trying to use Formula property in VBA must use the function names and arguments in English. It is not correct that this is due how VBA is designed. VBA is not a part of the Excel object model, which is a collection of COM objects written in C++. Excel just happens to provide this "VBA" scripting environment as a convenient tool to manipulate the COM object that it actually is. You can use any other language to manipulate it. For VBA, the contents of the formula is just a string, and it sees no more meaning in it than in any other string.

@GSerg; I have been using MS Excel for about 30 years. Actually, we are talking about the same things, but maybe I expressed it incompletely.
